# Debugging with .cab File in Crash Report (Windows Phone 7.x)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I looked at the Crash-Report for my Windows Phone App in the Dashboard. There is a Download-Link for a CAB-File for better debugging.

But i dont know how i can use this to debug. I found this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports.aspx

But I can't find the Symbols they fit for my App. It is a Windows Phone 7.x App. I find only Download-Links for the Windows Symbols. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must have all the debug folder of the version of your app you have on the store:

Especially all the .pdb files to be able to debug the file that comes from the store.